# sed replace word delimiter with multiple occurences of word

Tags: replace, sed

kinda new with sed. I made a script to replace various text in a file. As an example, file `test.txt` contains:

```
My name is <Jack>.
My dad calls me <Jack>. My mum calls me <Jack>, too.
```

I want to replace "<" and ">" with ":". I used this command

```
sed -re 's/<(.+?)>/:\1:/g' test.txt
```

It returns

```
My name is :Jack:.
My dad calls me :Jack>. My mum calls me <Jack:, too.
```

So, it works well with a single occurence in a line. The result is wrong with multiple occurrences in a line, because sed argument is all the text between the first "<" and the last ">".

Any hints? (And a little explaination, too...)

Thanks!

EDIT:

The same regular expression works correctly using replace in Gedit or other editors.

Answer (score 3):

easiest:

```
kent$  echo "My name is <Jack>.
dquote> My dad calls me <Jack>. My mum calls me <Jack>, too."|sed 's/[<>]/:/g'
My name is :Jack:.
My dad calls me :Jack:. My mum calls me :Jack:, too.
```

if you want to use group:

```
kent$  echo "My name is <Jack>.
My dad calls me <Jack>. My mum calls me <Jack>, too."|sed -r 's/<([^>]*)>/:\1:/g'
My name is :Jack:.
My dad calls me :Jack:. My mum calls me :Jack:, too.
```

In your codes, you want to use non-greedy matching, unfortunately, sed doesn't support that. So the reason why you got your output is:

the whole

```
<Jack>. My mum calls me <Jack>
```

is like `<....>`

the `.+` matches `Jack>. My mum calls me <Jack`

Comment: Alternatively, `s/<[^>]+>/:\1:/g`.

Comment: Thanks for the "sed doesn't support non-greedy matching" info. That explains why I can use the same regular expression in Gedit and it works (edited my question). I will analyze your code and test it. Can't use it straightforward since the actual replacement is a little more complicated than just replace "<>"; this was a brief example. Well, since I'm here asking... What if "Jack" is sorrounded, say, by an html tag (e.g. <a href="#anchor">Jack</a>)

Answer (score 0):

I update the example.

Here is test.html:

```
My name is <a href="filename.html#firstAnchor">Jack</a>.
My dad calls me <a href="filename.html#firstAnchor">Jack</a>. My mum calls me <a href="filename.html#secondAnchor">Jack</a>, too.
```

This command give me the expected result:

```
sed -re 's/<a href="filename.html#[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/:\1:/g' test.html
```

Result:

```
My name is :Jack:.
My dad calls me :Jack:. My mum calls me :Jack:, too.
```

sed search for the tag that starts with `<a href="filename.html#` and all following characters **but not** ">" (option `[^>]`), than search till ">". The argument is any char **but** "<" (option `[^<]`), than the delimiter is "</a>".

Did I get it?